# Definition of metric on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $\xi$ be a real vector bundle over a base space $B$. It is my understanding a metric is meant as a function,

$$\beta : E(\xi \oplus \xi) \to \mathbb R$$

where $E$ denotes the total space of the Whitney sum, such that, $\beta$ restricted to $p^{-1}(b) \times p^{-1}(b)$ is an inner product on $p^{-1}(b)$ for all $b \in B$. ($p$ is the projection.)

I am also aware the existence of a Gauss map guarantees that a real vector bundle admits a metric. I thus have two questions:

1. Is there no requirement that $\beta$ vary *continuously* from fibre to fibre?
2. Apart from the explicit construction, is there an *intuitive* reason why the existence of a Gauss map would guarantee the existence of  metric?

Comment: Typically $\beta$ is required to be more than just continuous so we don't demand it here, and it is implicitly understood to be "as smooth as $\xi$" although there are occasions where you want to relax that (e.g. you want to take limit but $C^\infty(B;E)$ is not a Banach space).

Comment: @user10354138 It seems that $\xi$ is a vector bundle over an arbitrary base space $B$ (as considered in $K$-theory). Smoothness is not defined in that case.

Comment: @PaulFrost the tag `differential-geometry` suggests the base $B$ is a differential manifold.

Comment: @user10354138 Maybe you are right ;-)

Comment: @user10354138 It is indeed an arbitrary base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\beta$ is required to be a continuous map.
2. I do not see how a Gauss map (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map) should be related to a metric on a vector bundle. The standard approach is this: Locally any bundle is trivial, hence locally you can find a metric. Then a partition of unity is used to piece together the local metrics to a global metric. See for example Hatcher 
   http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf p.11.

Edited:

A Gauss map in the sense of this question is a continuous map $g : E(\xi) \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that the restriction to each fiber is a linear monomorphism. Let $s : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be the usual inner product. We obtain a continuous map
$$\mu : E(\xi \oplus \xi) \to E(\xi) \times E(\xi) \stackrel{g \times g}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^m \stackrel{s}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}$$
which is the desired metric.

By the way, a Gauss map can be regarded as an embedding $\hat{g}$ of $\xi$ into the trivial m-dimensional bundle $\tau_m$ over $B$ (having total space $B \times \mathbb{R}^m$). In fact, define $\hat{g}(e) = (p(e),g(e))$.

Comment: The terminology of my book is probably old. By Gauss map, I mean a map $g :  E(\xi) \to F^m$ for a vector bundle in a field $F^m$. The map is such that it is a linear monomorphism, when restricted to a fibre.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Amazing notes by Hatcher, thanks for sharing this :)